# Как получить дату и время из интернета?

Tags: c++

Нужно получить дату и время из интернета. Для моей программы, ибо если брать дату с компьютера, то пользователь может ее поменять и обмануть программу. Я новичок в с++ и по этому не знаю как это сделать.
Я загуглил что это как то можно сделать с TIdSNTP, но как это подключить у себя в проекте я так и не нашел.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240530/free-rest-api-to-retrieve-current-datetime-as-string-timezone-irrelevant

Comment: Так как я чайник,честно говоря ссылка мне ничего не дала...Большая дискуссия какой API лучше и недействительные ссылки на API. Если это не составит труда(я абсолютно не представляю как получить дату и время из сети),то было бы неплохо дать какой нибудь пример.Смотрел,вроде с помощью TIdSNTP это не сложно сделать,но что это за библиотека и как ее подключить я не нашел...

Comment: Ссылка не работает, потому что вопросу 7 лет уже. Вы должны понимать, что если используете сторонний сервер, тем более бесплатный, он может в любой момент перестать работать. Если вы используете свой веб-сервер, лучше получать информацию с него. Сейчас попробую написать какой-нибудь пример со сторонним API.

Comment: Было бы супер,если если сделаете пример

Comment: Вы занимаетесь бессмысленным делом. Пользователь всегда может отредактировать программу (даже скомпилированную!) и сделать так, чтобы она получала именно такую дату, какую хочет подсунуть пользователь. Он может отключить любые обращения к интернету, если захочет. Именно так и работают пиратские кряки у всех программ. И к вашей программе тоже кто-нибудь однажды изобретёт кряк для подделки даты.

Comment: Ну извините,я не большая корпорация и знаний у меня ничтожно мало,так что для меня подойдет любой способ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример получения московского времени в формате UNIX через сервис http://worldtimeapi.org/ с помощью библиотеки [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk)

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/json.h>

using namespace web;                        // Common features like URIs.
using namespace web::http;                  // Common HTTP functionality
using namespace web::http::client;          // HTTP client features

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Make a GET request.
    auto requestJson = http_client(U("http://worldtimeapi.org"))
        .request(methods::GET,
            uri_builder(U("api/timezone/Europe/Moscow")).to_string())

        // Get the response.
        .then([](http_response response) {
        // Check the status code.
        if (response.status_code() != 200) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Returned " + std::to_string(response.status_code()));
        }

        // Convert the response body to JSON object.
        return response.extract_json();
    })

        .then([](json::value jsonObject) {
        return jsonObject[U("unixtime")];
    })

        .then([](json::value jsonObject) {
        std::cout << jsonObject.as_integer() << std::endl;
    });

    // Wait for the concurrent tasks to finish.
    try {
        requestJson.wait();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Заметьте, что стабильность работы сервиса не гарантируется.

> **Can I use it for commercial applications?**
>
> It is not recommended that this API be used for commercial
> applications. The API can go down from time-to-time, for relatively
> long periods. It is provided with no SLA, no guarantees, and no direct
> funding.
>
> Using this API for commercial applications is done entirely at your
> own risk. Development is ongoing, changes are made frequently, and
> there is no guarantee of stability or uptime.
>
> The project is entirely funded at a loss, and should costs become
> prohibitive the API will, with a heavy heart, be taken down
> permanently.
>
> If you require a stable platform with guaranteed uptime, we are happy
> to discuss provision of dedicated solutions for a monthly fee. Please
> contact us for more details.
>
> We would also like to ask users of this API to please consider
> contributing via a regular donation to help cover hosting costs and to
> keep this project alive.

http://worldtimeapi.org/pages/faqs#commercial-apps

Comment: у меня почему то ругается на пространство имен "utility" ,дабы нету такого

Comment: Странно, вы подключили библиотеку? Вообще, можете убрать эту строчку из кода, здесь utility не используется.

Comment: Да,я добавил в проект http_client.h, http_client.cpp и json.h , json.cpp,а в хедерах написал #include "http_client.h" и #include "json.h", но у меня ругается "methods","http_response","as_integer()" и U в строке U("http://worldtimeapi.org")

Comment: На гитхабе же есть инструкция по установке

Comment: http тоже можно легко обмануть, так что ваш ответ не подходит автору вопроса

Comment: У меня не получилось установить через vcpkg,пишет ошибка cmake ,без vcpkg никак нельзя?

Comment: Если у вас Visual Studio, вот инструкция https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio . Ищите там cpprestsdk